# Tensorflow 2 "Attempt to convert a value (63) with an unsupported type (<class 'numpy.int64'>) to a Tensor"

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

Taking the necessary code from the Tensorflow example for classifying structured data [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns) so that I can learn to train on Numeric columns; I get the following error:

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (63) with an unsupported type
>   () to a Tensor.

And while I suppose I could try to convert particular values in the dataframe to work with Tensors (if that would even work), there has to be something else going on as the code works in Colab but throws an error in PyCharm.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(URL)
dataframe.head()

train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
print(len(train), 'train examples')
print(len(val), 'validation examples')
print(len(test), 'test examples')

# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

feature_columns = []

# numeric cols
for header in ['age', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'thalach', 'oldpeak', 'slope', 'ca']:
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header))

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

batch_size = 32
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

"""## Create, compile, and train the model"""

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              run_eagerly=True)

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=5)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Numpy was corrupted. After uninstalling Numpy and re-installing it, the program worked.